# Tikz: Style depending on previous styles

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I would like to create a style that depends on other style values, for instance "if the current looseness is bigger than 2, don't change it, otherwise set it to 2". I'm also interested to know if there is a way to know if a given style (like `A` here) has been applied before.

For instance, here I would like the last wire to be more bended:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
Last wire should be more bended:
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  A/.style={in=0,out=0,looseness=1.2},
  B/.style={in=0,out=0,looseness=3},
  bn/.style={looseness=2} % Goal: min(current looseness, 2)
  ]
  \draw[A] (0,0) to (0,1);
  \draw[B] (1,0) to (1,1);
  \draw[A,bn] (2,0) to (2,1);
  \draw[B,bn] (3,0) to (3,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### EDIT

**I managed to solve my second question, but not the first one.**

So, following the idea of SebGlav, I managed to check if a style was later applied using `\pgfkeyssetvalue` (to create a new variable in a `.code`), `\pgfkeysalso` (to apply a style in a `.code`) and `\pgfkeysifdefined` to check if a key exists. It is possible to read the value of keys, and I guess

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
Last wire should be more bended:
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  A/.style={in=0,out=0,looseness=1.2},
  B/.code={%
    % Create a dummy key to check later
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{BIsUsed}{abc}%
    \tikzset{% Set the style of B
      in=0,out=0,looseness=4
    }
  },
  bn/.code={
    \pgfkeysifdefined{BIsUsed}{%
      \tikzset{% Style to apply if B was enabled before:
        %fill=red,
      }%
    }{% Style to apply if B was NOT enabled before
      \tikzset{%
        looseness=2,
        %fill=blue,
      }
    }%
  }
  ]
  \draw[A] (0,0) to (0,1);
  \draw[B] (1,0) to (1,1);
  \draw[A,bn] (2,0) to (2,1);
  \draw[B,bn] (3,0) to (3,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For the first question, I tried that, but it tells me that `\pgfk@looseness` is an undefined control sequence.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\begin{document}
Last wire should be more bended:
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  A/.style={in=0,out=0,looseness=1.2},
  B/.code={%
    in=0,out=0,looseness=4
  },
  bn/.code={
    \ifthenelse{\pgfkeysvalueof{looseness} < 2}{}{%
      \pgfkeysalso{% Style to apply if B was enabled before:
        looseness=2
      }%
    }{}
  }
  ]
  \draw[A] (0,0) to (0,1);
  \draw[B] (1,0) to (1,1);
  \draw[A,bn] (2,0) to (2,1);
  \draw[B,bn] (3,0) to (3,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try with a global variable?

Comment: @SebGlav global variables indeed help for the second question, see my edit. Thanks a lot! But the first question is still open...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `looseness` isn't a value key. (And if it were, you'd need to use `\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/looseness}`).

The `looseness` key is more or less just a shortcut for `in looseness` and `out looseness` and these, too, aren't plain value keys.

They call a macro that evaluates the given value and store it in a macro and also activate further computation. Just giving them alone activates the whole bending spiel:

```
\tikz\draw (0,0) to[looseness=1] (2,2);
```

This already draws a bended line with the default values `out = 45` and `in = 135` which – you guessed it – aren't pure value keys either.

The macros the values are getting stored in are `\tikz@to@set@out@looseness` and `\tikz@to@set@in@looseness` which you could check for and/or even set global but then they would be set for all following paths even if they don't have `bn` style set.

We can, however, append code to the `looseness` key:

```
looseness/.append code={\gdef\tikzLooseness{#1}},
```

and access the previously set `looseness` that way, for `bn` we just do

```
bn/.code={%
  \pgfmathifthenelse{\tikzLooseness<2}{2}{\tikzLooseness}%
  \tikzset{looseness=\pgfmathresult}%
}
```

(No need for the `ifthen` package, we have PGFmath built-in.)

Caveats:

- You can override `looseness` again when given after `bn`.
- `out looseness` and `in looseness` are not patched.
- The `\global`ization isn't nice but I couldn't finde a nice hook to set a macro right after the `\path <…>;`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\def\tikzLooseness{1}% TikZ default
\tikzset{
  bn/.code={%
    \pgfmathifthenelse{\tikzLooseness<2}{2}{\tikzLooseness}%
    \tikzset{looseness=\pgfmathresult}%
  },
  looseness/.append code={\gdef\tikzLooseness{#1}},
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  A/.style={in=0, out=0, looseness=1.2},
  B/.style={in=0, out=0, looseness=4},
  n/.style={insert path={node[below, font=\tiny, node contents={#1}]}}
  ]
  \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid[step=.5] (2.5,1);
  \draw[A, dashed]  (0,0) [n=A] to +(90:1);
  \draw[B, dashed]  (1,0) [n=B] to +(90:1) [thick];
  \draw[A, bn]      (0,0)       to +(90:1);
  \draw[B, bn]      (1,0)       to +(90:1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]